# SQL query to display the name of each horse, together with the number of events in which it has won and not won

Tags: sql, ms-access

These are the following tables I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE Horse
(horse_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 horse_name CHAR(30),
 horse_colour CHAR(30)
 horse_sire INTEGER,
 horse_dam INTEGER,
 horse_born INTEGER.
 horse_died INTEGER,
 horse_gender CHAR(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Entry
(horse_id INTEGER,
 entry_place INTEGER
);
```

Then I added the following values for these 2 tables:

```
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (101,'Flash','white',201,301,1990,'S');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (102,'Star','brown',201,302,1991,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (201,'Boxer','grey',401,501,1980,'S');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_gender)
VALUES (301,'Daisy','white',401,502,1981,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_sire,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (302,'Tinkle','brown',401,501,1981,1994,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (401,'Snowy','white',301,1976,1984,'S');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (501,'Bluebell','grey',301,1975,1982,'M');
INSERT INTO Horse (horse_id,horse_name,horse_colour,horse_dam,horse_born,horse_died,horse_gender)
VALUES (502,'Sally','white',301,1974,1987,'M');

INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (101,1);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (102,2);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (201,3);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (301,4);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (201,2);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (102,3);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (101,1);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (301,2);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (102,7);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (102,1);
INSERT INTO Entry (horse_id,entry_place)
VALUES (301,3);
```

This is the question:

**List the name of each horse, together with the number of events in which it has
been awarded first place. Horses who have never won a first place should also be listed
with a count of zero. Sort the list into descending order on number of wins.**

**The output of this query should be as shown below:**

```
Horse  Number of wins

Flash          2
Star           1
Bluebell       0
Boxer          0
Daisy          0
Sally          0
Snowy          0
Tinkle         0
```

This is what I have tried in my first attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Horse.horse_name ,COUNT(Entry.entry_place) AS [Number of Wins]
FROM Horse, Entry 
WHERE Horse.horse_id = Entry.horse_id 
AND entry_place =1 OR (NOT entry_place = 1)
GROUP by Horse.horse_name
ORDER BY  Entry.entry_place DESC;
```

I got the following error message:

```
ORDER BY clause (Entry.entry_place) conflicts with DISTINCT
```

Then this is what I have tried in my second attempt:

```
SELECT Horse.horse_name ,COUNT(Entry.entry_place) AS [Number of Wins]
FROM Horse, Entry 
WHERE Horse.horse_id = Entry.horse_id 
AND entry_place =1 OR (NOT entry_place = 1)
GROUP by Horse.horse_name
ORDER BY  Entry.entry_place DESC;
```

I got the following error message:

```
Your query does not include the specified expression 'Entry.entry_place' as part of an aggregate function.
```

I still could not figure out where is the mistake in my code.
It would be really helpful if the solution code is provided so that I can get the desired output from the query based on what the question wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split this up.

To count the wins, use a subquery:

```
SELECT horse_id, COUNT(*) AS CountWin
FROM Entry
WHERE entry_place = 1
GROUP BY horse_id
```

To show all horses, you need a LEFT JOIN between Horses and the subquery:

```
SELECT Horse.horse_name, Wins.CountWin
FROM Horse
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT horse_id, COUNT(*) AS CountWin
    FROM Entry
    WHERE entry_place = 1
    GROUP BY horse_id
) AS Wins
ON Horse.horse_id = Wins.horse_id
```

This returns `NULL` for horses that have never won, not `0`.
So we use `Nz()` to fix that. Plus the sorting:

```
SELECT Horse.horse_name, Nz(Wins.CountWin, 0) AS [Number of Wins]
FROM Horse
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT horse_id, COUNT(*) AS CountWin
    FROM Entry
    WHERE entry_place = 1
    GROUP BY horse_id
) AS Wins
ON Horse.horse_id = Wins.horse_id
ORDER BY Wins.CountWin DESC, Horse.horse_name ASC
```

@Everyone: Please read the question tags. And just dumping a block of SQL without any explanations on a homework question isn't too helpful IMO.

---

**Edit:** You can adapt Pallavi's code for Access, using `IIf()`. But while it is shorter, I find it less easy to understand.

```
SELECT 
    Horse.horse_name, 
    SUM(IIf(Entry.entry_place=1, 1, 0)) AS [Number of Wins]
FROM Horse LEFT JOIN Entry 
ON Horse.horse_id = Entry.horse_id
GROUP by Horse.horse_name
ORDER BY SUM(IIf(Entry.entry_place=1, 1, 0)) DESC
```

(Note: untested in Access)

Comment: I tried your code and it worked perfectly :)  . What I would like to know that is there any other simpler and alternative code to get the same result ?

Comment: This code is even better :)  . I just have one small doubt. I understood the logic of IIF(Entry.entry_place=1). But after that when you have again added 1,0.   What is the logic of adding 1,0 again ?

Comment: (I think) you can't use `[Number of Wins]` in the ORDER BY clause, so you have to repeat the original expression. It doesn't matter in the query designer, there it is all in one column.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this:

SELECT Horse.horse_name, SUM(CASE WHEN entry_place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins
FROM Horse LEFT OUTER JOIN Entry 
ON ( Horse.horse_id = Entry.horse_id )
GROUP by Horse.horse_name
ORDER BY Wins desc;
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM'(CASE WHEN entry_place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'.

Comment: Note that I am using MS-Access here.

Comment: Could you suggest to the op why this will help them - what you changed in respect to their question?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Horse.horse_name, SUM(CASE entry_place WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Wins
FROM Horse LEFT OUTER JOIN Entry 
ON ( Horse.horse_id = Entry.horse_id )
GROUP by Horse.horse_name
ORDER BY Wins desc;
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM'(CASE entry_place  WHEN1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'.

Answer (score -2):

use it; this is the best answer ; enjoy it;

```
select distinct h.horse_name,
case
when e.entry_place='1' then sum(e.entry_place) 
else '0'
end as [Number of wins]
from horse h 
left join entry e on h.horse_id=e.horse_id
group by h.horse_name,e.entry_place
order by [Number of wins] desc;
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'case
when e.entry_place='1' then sum(e.entry_place) 
else '0'
end.

Comment: This query can surely work in SQL Server. But, it is very unlikely that this same query will work in Microsoft Access. I think the query syntax will be bit different in Microsoft Access.

Comment: If you look into my tag. It is MS-Access. Not SQL Server. It would be helpful if you can test it in MS-Access.

Comment: Starting with _this is the best answer_, then proceeding with something that clearly causes a syntax error, then asking for upvotes is not the best plan. Rewriting it for Access is easy, though.

Comment: i saw the sql tag also so i answered in sql